# Configuring Fabric For EC2

Tags: python, deployment, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, fabric

I am trying to create a fabfile.py so that I can deploy on EC2. I have the following in my fabfile.py:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from fabric.api import *


def ec2():
    env.hosts = ['111.111.111.111'] 
    env.user = 'ubuntu'
    env.key_filename = '/path/to/my/pem/key.pem'

def run_ls():
    run('ls -alt')
```

'111.111.111.111' is the elastic ip of my instance, and i alway login with ubuntu, not root.
when i run the following command

```
fab ec2 run_ls
```

i see the following output:

```
[111.111.111.111] Executing task 'run_ls'
[111.111.111.111] run: ls -alt

Fatal error: Host key for 111.111.111.111 did not match pre-existing key! Server's key was changed recently, or possible man-in-the-middle attack.

Aborting.
```

Not sure what is going on, but I can't find to seem any great tutorials on using fabric on ec2, and I do not know how that is possible.

Thanks

### Update:

Looks like

```
env.hosts = ['111.111.111.111']
```

is not valid, you need to use the actually URL

```
env.hosts = ['mywebsite.com']
```

which fixed my issue

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure your elastic IP is attached to the instance.  I think the key_filename takes a single argument but mine is working when you pass in an array instead:

```
env.user = "ubuntu"
env.key_filename = ["my_key.pem",]
```

Maybe you should try using the public hostname of your instance like:

```
env.roledefs.update({
    'prod': ['ec2-52-14-72-225.us-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com'],
})
```

Comment: this does not fix the issue.  by supplying diff hostname to connect to same box, you are simply masking the issue.  the old hostname/hostkey will still cause fatal error.   fix is supplied in other comments.... either remove hostkey from knownhosts, or "fab --disable-known-hosts [hostlist] [function]"

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the '--disable-known-hosts' switch to ignore this error.

Comment: @hamish-downer: You can try deleting (or renaming) your known_hosts file. mv ~/.ssh/known_hosts ~/.ssh/known_hosts_old

Comment: works for me: "fab --disable-known-hosts [hostlist] [function]"

Answer (score 4):

From [a  Vagrant issue on GitHub](https://github.com/wutali/vagrant-fabric/issues/5), you may need to remove the host from the `known_hosts` file using a command like this:

```
ssh-keygen -R 111.111.111.111
```

Comment: this is much cleaner than vi'ing ~/.ssh/known_hosts +1